# Style all Bootstrap 3 navbar links except those under ul

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

Style all anchors/links:

```
.navbar li a {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

Style anchors/links under ul:

```
.navbar ul li a {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

I would like to achieve 2 different scenarios:

- Style all links, except those under ul
- Style all links, except those under class *.dropdown-menu* (ul)

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v2xmc150/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean all nested links should not be colored blue? if so change the css as below.

```
.navbar li a {
  color: blue !important;
}

/* Link under ul only */
.navbar ul.dropdown-menu li a {
  color:initial !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this selector to style only the first ul. and the under color is different

```
  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: blue !important;
  }
```

see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v2xmc150/2/